# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. (I am Using sub query as column expression.)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select e.first_name+' '+e.last_name As FullName, j.job_title, 
(
    Select Max(start_date) As StartDate, Max(end_date) As EndDate
    From job_history as jh1
    Where jh1.employee_id = e.employee_id
    Group by employee_id
)    
From employees e, jobs j
Where e.job_id = j.job_id
And e.commission_pct = 0;
```

I would like to return the last job starting and ending dates of some employees. who don't get commissions and name (From employees
table) and job_title (From jobs table). If a sub query is used as a
column can't we have more than single column in it?

Comment: Either use 2 sub-queries, one for each new column value, or join your sub-query on and reference it that way.

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1):

A CROSS APPLY may be what you need:

```
Select e.first_name+' '+e.last_name As FullName, T.StartDate , T.EndDate
From employees e
Join jobs j On e.job_id = j.job_id 
Cross Apply (
    Select Max(start_date) As StartDate, Max(end_date) As EndDate
    From job_history as jh1
    Where jh1.employee_id = e.employee_id
) As T
Where e.commission_pct = 0
```

I also recommend moving the commission_pct test into the WHERE as shown above, since it is really not functioning as a join condition.

The CTE group-by, subquery group-by, and cross-apply answers given so far all accomplish (almost*) the same thing. Which is used is partly a matter of style, but they may also have performance differences depending on what portion of the data (% of employees) are being selected. If the % is high, the CTE and subqueries may perform better by preprocessing all job history data at once. If the percentage is small, there may be an advantage with cross apply only accessing that data needed for the result.

(* As noted by Charlieface in the comments below, there is a difference in behavior if an employee has no matching job history. The above outer-apply will always match, and may yield null StartDate and EndDate values. The CTE and subqueries -based answers perform an inner join which may exclude such an employee. The latter answers c an be easily changed to left-joins. You will need to decide on the preferred behavior.)

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` on a subquery which has an aggregate and no `GROUP BY` effectively becomes a `OUTER APPLY` due to the fact the aggregate is a scalar aggregate ([always returns one row](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/03/fun-with-aggregates.html)), to force it to filter out rows with no matches you need to add a seemingly redundant `GROUP BY ()`

Comment: @Charlieface - Good catch. There is a difference. Begs the question: What would the OP (or the OP's customer) want in this edge case ever came up - Ignore the employee or show the employee with no job history (null start/end)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is impossible.
you can easily solve this by joining or you can write a function for max, min and find it for any id and return the result by typing SQL in it.

*it should work that way:*

```
Select e.first_name+' '+e.last_name As FullName, T.StartDate , T.EndDate
From employees e INNER JOIN  jobs j
ON e.job_id = j.job_id and e.commission_pct = 0 
INNER JOIN (   
Select Max(start_date) As StartDate, Max(end_date) As EndDate
    From job_history as jh1
Group by jh1.employee_id 
) AS T 
ON T.employee_id = e.employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common table expression:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT employee_id, 
           Max(start_date) As StartDate, 
           Max(end_date) As EndDate
    FROM job_history
    GROUP by employee_id
)
SELECT e.first_name+' '+e.last_name As FullName, 
       j.job_title, 
       C.StartDate , C.EndDate
FROM employees e 
INNER JOIN  jobs j
    ON e.job_id = j.job_id 
INNER JOIN CTE C
    ON C.employee_id = e.employee_Id
WHERE e.commission_pct = 0
```